# How to change colour of variable storing a string in C

Tags: c, terminal, ansi-colors

I'm programming in C and I've read a lot about how to change the colour of a string. But I'm wondering how to change the colour of a string when it is stored as a variable. For Instance:

```
printf ("\e[1;31m Hello \e[0m\n");
```

This would change the colour of "Hello" to red. But what if "Hello" was stored in a variable like this:

```
char myString[] = "Hello";
```

How could we incorporate myString into the bash code above in the printf statement to change the colour of "Hello" through the variable holding the value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a "bash code" and has nothing to do with your shell.

Comment: There isn't any Bash code in the question.  You probably create a variable `red=$'\e[1;31m'` and `plain=$'\e[0m'`, and then you use `echo "$red$myString$plain"` or `printf "%s%s%s\n" "$red" "$myString" "$plain"`.

Comment: You can use `%s` to `printf` the contents of string variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can't , what you can do is make a simple structure that holds the string and it's color:

```
struct ColoredString
{
    char myString[100];
    char coloredString[50];
}
```

Use:

```
struct ColoredString cs; 
strcpy(cs.myString,"Hello");

SetColor(cs,"\e[1;31m", "\e[0m");

puts(cs.coloredString);
```

SetColor function:

```
void SetColor(ColoredString cs, char *c1, char* c2)
{
    strcpy(cs.coloredString,c1);
    strcat(cs.coloredString,cs.myString);
    strcat(cs.coloredString,c2);
}
```

Comment: Its suppose to be the same string that you printed  , worked when i tried it